# write to OS register HKLM when installing a MSIX package

Tags: msix

I need to write to the OS register by creating a HKLM key. This needs to be done during installation of a MSIX package.

I realize the windowsapp runs in a virtualized environment and the HKLM key is virtually visible to the app when it is running. The challenge is the only way the app works, is if the HKLM key is permanently written to the OS register and I disable virtualized reqister keys.

Tried a windows powershell to execute on windows app install but it doesn't write to the OS register with a new key under HKLM. Not sure if I need admin writes - the MSIX package installs with FULLTRUST so assume this isn't an issue.